# html5 input validation preventing asp grid view button press

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

My page consists of html5 inputs and asp grid view. When I try to press the gird view button on any row, the HTML5 input validation message is displayed. I can not use grid asp buttons without filling the mandatory fields of the form but I do not require to fill the form for using grid view.

I want that the HTML5 input validation should work only for the submit button not for all the buttons in the page. How can I do that?

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="box box-default">            
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input_text" runat="server" id="inputType" placeholder="BILLING TYPE" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2" ControlToValidate="inputType" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="btnSubmitClick" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Amount</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input_text" runat="server" id="inputAmount" placeholder="BILLING AMOUNT" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv3" ControlToValidate="inputAmount" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="btnSubmitClick" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"
                                CausesValidation="true"
                                ValidationGroup="btnSubmitClick"
                                OnClientClick="if (!Page_ClientValidate()){ return false; } this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Saving...';"
                                UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="adminScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="div_grid" runat="server">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
                                runat="server"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                Width="100%"
                                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                CssClass="gridview"
                                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No." ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>                                    
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BILLING_AMOUNT"
                                        HeaderText="AMOUNT">
                                        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CREATED_BY"
                                        HeaderText="CREATED BY">
                                        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnBilled" CommandName="ChangeStatus" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")+","+ Eval("BILL_STATUS")%>' Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("BILL_STATUS")) ? "DISABLE" : "ENABLE" %>' runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I press the asp Button ID="btnBilled" in the grid view, the html5 validation for the input field inputType is shown. How can I bypass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CausesValidation` is to validate asp.net validators not HTML5 validation.

I used the property `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBilled" CommandName="ChangeStatus" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")+","+ Eval("BILL_STATUS")%>' Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("BILL_STATUS")) ? "DISABLE" : "ENABLE" %>' runat="server" 
CausesValidation="false" />
```

It worked.

Answer (score -1):

set CausesValidation="false" on the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBilled" CommandName="ChangeStatus" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")+","+ Eval("BILL_STATUS")%>' Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("BILL_STATUS")) ? "DISABLE" : "ENABLE" %>' runat="server" 
CausesValidation="false" />
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it's not working. Still getting HTML5 validation message from the textbox.